# element wise addition of n lists output in for loop

Tags: python

I am trying to simulate results for a game with `n` players.
A for loop is outputting lists of length `n`. I want to add up all the lists in the loop and divide by `n`.

Here is my code:

```
import random

def list_fun(n):
  randomlist = []
  for i in range(n):
    n = random.randint(0,1)
    randomlist.append(n)
  return(randomlist)

def list_multi(n):
  for i in range(n):
    res = list_fun(n)
    print(res)
    # instead of print output element wise sum of lists
  return None

list_multi(5)

Output:
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1]

Desired output/return:
[3, 3, 2, 2, 1]  / n
```

---

For only 2 players I tried this. It works fine, but adding more players gets messy with this approach.

```
res = []
for i in range(n):
    res += list_fun(n)
print(sum(res[::2])/n)
print(sum(res[1::2])/n)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put all your lists in a single list of lists (`M` below) then you can sum the columns all up at once with `zip` with something like

```
[sum(l)/n for l in zip(*M)]
```

So the complete code with an extra print to see the matrix might look like this:

```
import random

def list_fun(n):
    return [random.randint(0,1) for i in range(n)]

def list_multi(n):
    M = [list_fun(n) for i in range(n)]
    print(M)
    return [sum(l)/n for l in zip(*M)]

# M will be something like:
# [[1, 0, 1, 0, 0], 
#  [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
#  [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
#  [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
#  [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]]

list_multi(5)
# [1.0, 0.4, 0.6, 0.4, 0.6]
```

###### Edit for comment:

if you don't want to store the whole matrix, you can just add the lists as they are created. You can start with a list of zeros so the first `zip` works. The distribute the division as you add.

```
def list_multi(n):
    total = [0] * n
    for _ in range(n):
        total = [a + (b / n) for a, b, in zip(total, list_fun(n))]
    return total
```

Comment: Assuming I don't want to put all the outcomes into one list, how could I add after every iteration to some results list/vector? As n increases it might be hard on memory and I might prefer slower computation with less memory.

Comment: Good one. But I'd change the letter `l` in your list comprehension to something else as it looks a lot like `1`!

Comment: @HansDieter88 see the edit above for one way to do this without storing the list.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. 
Notice that you can rewrite `res[::2]` as `res[0::2]`:

```
res = []
for i in range(n):
  res += list_fun(n)
for j in range(n):
  print(sum(res[j::n])/n)
  # runs for j = 0, then j = 1, ... up to j = n - 1
```

Complete snippet:

```
import random

def list_fun(n):
  randomlist = []
  for i in range(n):
    n = random.randint(0,1)
    randomlist.append(n)
  return(randomlist)

def list_multi(n):
  res = []
  for i in range(n):
    res += list_fun(n)
  for j in range(n):
    print(sum(res[j::n])/n)

list_multi(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic approach would be to use the *[sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)* method for each *list_fun* call.

```py
def list_multi(n):
    value = 0
    for i in range(n):
        value += sum(list_fun(n))
    return value / n
```

Additionally, you could create each *list*, and accumulate the totals.

```py
def list_multi(n):
    values = [0] * n
    for i in range(n):
        for index, value in enumerate(list_fun(n)):
            values[index] += value
    print(values)
    return sum(values) / n
```